# correct declaration of variables in swift

Tags: swift

Hi I'm new to swift language, first of all I don't know if this is a permitable topic I'm creating but I need to understand this and couldn't find any information on the web for this

in swift I realized there's a couple of ways for declaring a variable and it's type. but I don't know the differences and don't know where to use which..

correct me If I am wrong..
to begin with: when

```
var anything = "When I do it like this my anything variable becomes type of string"
```

but if I type

```
var anything = 12 //it's type Int
```

and so on.. apart from this I could also declare these variables as

```
var anything:Int
```

or

```
var anything:String
```

so far I'm good with this but what is the difference of declaring a global variable as

```
var anything:String
```

or

```
var anything:String = String()
```

how do I decide to use which and where? thank you

Comment: Btw just don't forget that you should always use "let" if it is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Swift types can be inferred (determined from the context). In

```
var anything: Int = 12
```

`Int` is redundant as it can be inferred form context (`Int` is default for integer literals). However sometimes you need more specific like `Int8`. You can then explicitly declare the type or use initialiser to infer the type type:

```
var anything: Int8 = 12
```

or

```
var anything = Int8(12)
```

Personally I used type inferring whenever I can and haven't run into any problems yet.

Comment: what is the difference of 
var anything:String 
var anything:String = 12
and 
var anything:String = String()

Comment: 1) Declaration of `String` variable 2) Syntax error 3) Declaration of `String` variable and assigning empty string to it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start backwards. What is the difference between 
`var anything:String` and `var anything:String = String()`

The first one *declares* a variable called `anything` of type `String` and the second *initializes* it by calling String's constructor. In the first case you will have to tell Swift's compiler what to expect from this variable - will it have a value or it will be nil. So the best thing to do if you don't know this is to declare it as *optional*:

`var anything:String?`

About the types that you initialize like this `var anything = 12`, Swift determines the type by the context, in this case it is an `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very basic, but I understand the trouble of learning a new language and that you need help. It is the standard learning curve.

Swift uses a technique called type inference. It can determine the type of a variable from the initial value.

```
var v = 8
```

automatically make v an Int.

```
var v:Int = 8
```

does the same

You can always use inferred types. Try to make your code readable and if type-inference improves the readability, then use it. 
If you need more context to be able to understand your code 2 weeks after writing it, use explicitly declared types.

When you declare variables without an initial value you always have to declare the type explicitly. In this case, the compiler does not have any chance to guess the type.

Comment: var:Int won’t work ;) You’ll still have to give the variable a name